# jQuery .after() with the same behavior as .html()

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to insert some html after a particular element, but since this action is executed multiple times, I don't want an append behavior because I'd be getting repeated html.

Let's say I have this:

```
<div id="element">
```

And every time the action is executed I'd do `$('#element').after(data)` so it'd look like this:

```
<div id="element">
whatever data
```

However if the action is executed again I'get this:

```
<div id="element">
whatever data
other data appended
```

How could I achieve a `.html(data)` behavior?

I know I could do this wrapping what's next of '#element' and use `$('#wrapper).html(data)` but I actually can't because it messes up with the css.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give an id to the appended div and conditionally check and if that exists then append in that:

```
var strToAppend = 'whatever data';
if($('#foo').length == 1){
  $('#foo').text(strToAppend);
} else {
  $('#element').after('<div id="foo">'+strToAppend+'</div>');
}
```